# Algebraic Indepence of Functions over Infinite Field

Tags: field-theory, representation-theory

Can someone point in the right direction to a reference or give me an idea of the proof of the following fact.  My field theory is rusty:

Let $K$ be an infinite field of arbitrary characteristic.  Let $A$ be the $K$-algebra generated by all maps $f:GL_n(K)\to K.$  Consider the subalgebra generated by $c_{ij}:GL_n(K) \to K$ definied by $c_{ij}(A) = a_{ij}$ that is $c_{ij}$ picks out the $ij$-entry of the matrix $A.$

> Since $K$ is infinite the elements $c_{ij}$ are algebraically independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f \in K[x_{ij}]$ be a polynomial that vanishes when we plug in $x_{ij} = c_{ij}$.  Note that the $c_{ij}$ are the restrictions of similar functions defined on the set of all matrices $\mathbb M_n(K)$, and in this setting $f$ is a polynomial that vanishes on all of $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$.

We can also consider the determinant to be a polynomial $\det \in K[x_{ij}]$.  As $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$ are exactly those matrices for which $\det$ is nonzero this means that the polynomial $f\cdot\det \in K[x_{ij}]$ vanishes on all of $\mathbb M_n(K)$.

Now prove by induction on $n$ that if $g \in K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ evaluates to zero on all of $K^n$ then in fact $g = 0$ in $K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$.

P.s. In case you know anything about algebraic geometry: In algebraic geometry terms what you are doing is proving that affine space $\mathbb M_n(K) \simeq \mathbb A^{n^2}$ is irreducible, so open subsets (like $\mathrm{GL}_n(K)$) are dense, and hence not contained in the zero set of any polynomial.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I needed!